# Remove elements in function that cause it to stop in R

Tags: r, list, function, error-handling

I have two simple functions: `f1` and `f2`. **Suppose we only have access to `f2`**. How  can I remove any piece of output in `f2` that causes `f1` to `stop` and return the rest of the output?

*My desired output is shown below the code.*

```
# FUNCTION #1:
f1 <- function(...){

   r <- list(...)
   lapply(seq_along(r), function(i) if(r[[i]] == 4) stop("Problem") else r[[i]] + 1)
}

# FUNCTION #2:
f2 <- function(...){

   res <- try(f1(...), silent = TRUE)

  # if any 'res' causes 'stop' remove it, and return the rest!
}

# EXAMPLE:
f2(1, 2, 4)
```

**My Desired output is:**

```
#[[1]]
#[1] 1

#[[2]]
#[1] 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic in f1 seems to stop everything if any of the `...` input gets an error.

So, in f2, you could feed inputs into f1 one by one, normal input will get the correct output.

```r
f1 <- function(...){

   r <- list(...)
     lapply(seq_along(r), function(i) if(r[[i]] == 4) stop("Problem") else r[[i]] + 1)
}

# FUNCTION #2:
f2 <- function(...){

   # res <- try(f1(...), silent = TRUE)
  r <- list(...)
  res = lapply(r, function(fluffybunny){
    tmp =try(f1(fluffybunny))
    if(class(tmp) =="try-error") tmp=NULL
    return(tmp)
  })
  # if any 'res' causes 'stop' remove it, and return the rest!

  res.remove_error =res[!sapply(res, is.null)]
   return(res.remove_error)
}

# EXAMPLE:
result = f2(1, 2, 4)
#> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Problem

result
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]][[1]]
#> [1] 3
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

---

Edit: removed result with `try-error` from f2's output.

Comment: Please see my desired output at the end of my R code?

Comment: I think it's reasonable to expect the output having the same length as the input, The error output can be further processed. For example, what if you input f2(1,2,4,5)? according to your desired output, it should output (2,3,6). If you are ok with this, I can update my answer.